# R - ggplot2 trace lines between "stacked" points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems to figure how I can trace lines (and ultimately arrows) between two points on top of each others. So my basic plot looks like this :

```
 dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = V2, y = V3, colour = V1) ) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('gray44', 'black')) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) + geom_text(aes(x = V2, y = V3+1.05, label = V1))
```

[image]

So, I tried to create "groups" in order to trace a line but it doesn't work, 
what I want is that the points that are on top of each others get connected:

```
dt = dt %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(grp = 1:n())

dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = V2, y = V3, colour = V1) ) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('gray44', 'black')) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) + geom_text(aes(x = V2, y = V3+1.05, label = V1)) +
  geom_path(data = dt, aes(V2, V3, group = grp))
```

Ultimately, I would be very interested to trace an arrow going from `1985` to `1990`, but I can't figure it

I tried to add something like :

```
geom_segment(aes(x = V3[V1 == 1985], y = V3[V1 == 1985], xend = V3[V1 == 2000], yend = V3[V1 == 2000]), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

[image]

```
dt = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1985", 
"1990"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), V3 = c(60, 
40, 60, 80, 20, 40)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `group=V2` instead of grp.

Comment: cool thank you. I didn't of it. Thanks so much. Will it work with the arrow to ? thanks

Comment: Arrow() only changes the tips so there shouldn't be any issue with that.

Comment: I can't make the arrows right. They go in weird direction. Could you help me to make the arrows goes from `1985` to `1990` ? thanks

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: `geom_segment(data = dt, aes(x = V2, y = V3, xend = V2, yend = V3, group = V2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))`, so the arrows are pointing towards each values, instead of being from one year to the other. Many thanks.

Comment: Try with this instead : `geom_path(data = dt, aes(V2, V3, group = V2),arrow= arrow(angle = 15, ends = "both", type = "closed"))` and lmk.